# Can I restrict warnings to my project's includes instead of all includes with llvm or gcc?

Tags: gcc, compiler-warnings, llvm

I would like to restrict certain warnings to project includes, so system includes are not checked. So:

```
/* I want no warnings from this include */
#include <myheader.h>

/* I want warnings from this include */
#include "myotherheader.h"
```

Is this possible with llvm and/or gcc?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1):

GCC already does this - you can specify additional directories to be considered as 'system directories' if you have some headers that you want to suppress warnings for:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

I don't really know about llvm/clang, but since clang has an option, `-Wsystem-headers`, to enable warnings from system headers I'd assume it does something similar to GCC for system headers (i.e., suppress warnings for them).

Comment: Can GCC distinguish the two types based on the 'quote type' ("" vs. <>) without using -isystem? At least on the compilers shipped with Xcode 4.0.2, both included files generate warnings.